# how to expand the polygon to reach nearby line in r?

Tags: r, polygon, spatial

Let say i have a SpatialPolygons object with 3 polygons data name `groupexc`:

```
library(raster) 
p1 <- matrix(c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4), ncol=2)
p2 <- matrix(c(8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4), ncol=2)
p3 <- matrix(c(5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 9, 10, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 8, 9), ncol=2)
groupexc <- spPolygons(p1, p2, p3)
```

And a SpatialPolygons object `zoneexc` that represents a single zone:

```
zoneexc = spPolygons(matrix(c(2,1,3,4,6,8,10,13,14,14,12,10,8,6,4,2,1,3,7,10,12,14,12,6,4,3,1,1,1,1,1,1), ncol=2))
```

Is there a way for me to expand the output from `groupexc` until it reach points in `zoneexc`?

before

```
plot(zoneexc, border='red', lwd=3)
plot(groupexc, add=TRUE, border='blue', lwd=2)
text(groupexc, letters[1:3])
```

[image]

after:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please provide the data as code like `groupexc <- cbind(c(1,2,3), c(1,2,3))` (and see `raster::spPolygons` to make polygons.)

Comment: im sorry i have tried but i dont know how to

Comment: i didnt need any specific condition.myb they can expand fairly until they reach point to `zoneexc`. i just need it to be expand so that there is no hole in my polygon

Comment: no sorry was wrong.i just want to expand it until its exterior part

Comment: i have edit my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approximate solution. This approach might break for large problems, and it depends on having sufficient number of nodes in each polygon. But it may be good enough for your purpose.

```
# example data 
library(raster) 
p1 <- matrix(c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4), ncol=2)
p2 <- matrix(c(8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4), ncol=2)
p3 <- matrix(c(5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 9, 10, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 8, 9), ncol=2)
groups <- spPolygons(p1, p2, p3, attr=data.frame(name=c('a', 'b', 'c')))
zone <- spPolygons(matrix(c(2,1,3,4,6,8,10,13,14,14,12,10,8,6,4,2,1,3,7,10,12,14,12,6,4,3,1,1,1,1,1,1), ncol=2))
```

Now create nearest neighbor polygons. For this to work as below, you need **dismo version 1.1-1** (or higher)

```
library(dismo)
# get the coordinates of the polygons    
g <- unique(geom(groups))
v <- voronoi(g[, c('x', 'y')], ext=extent(zone))
# plot(v)
# assign group id to the new polygons
v$group <- g[v$id, 1]

# aggregate (dissolve) polygons by group id
a <- aggregate(v, 'group')
# remove areas outside of the zone
i <- crop(a, zone)

# add another identifier 
i$name <- groups$name[i$group]

plot(i, col=rainbow(3))
text(i, "name", cex=2)
plot(groups, add=TRUE, lwd=2, border='white', lty=2)
```

[image: white lines show original areas, now expanded to fill up the zone]

To see how it works:

```
points(g[, c('x', 'y')], pch=20, cex=2)
plot(v, add=TRUE)
```

Comment: whats the -999 for?

Comment: this is work with the data. but when i am using my data, it says, Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, name, value = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  : 
  replacement has 8400 rows, data has 8395). do u have any idea why its become like this?

Comment: it happen at here, v$group <- g[,1]. i will try to learn to make my data available via fileshare. i actually didnt know how to share my data

Comment: and after i do geom, the variable name for a,b,c is gone. how can i keep it?

Comment: i think it is because like u said it will have problems if data is big. i can run it smoothly by using smaller sample.

Comment: where can i get your email?

Comment: i didnt get what u get.  Error in voronoi(g[, c("x", "y")], ext = extent(zone)) : 
  unused argument (ext = extent(zone))

Comment: Then you are not using dismo version 1.1-1